# Okta API - how to return assigned applications that are set to not be shown to users

Tags: okta, okta-api

When I use the Okta API endpoint [/users/:id/appLinks](http://developer.okta.com/docs/api/resources/users.html#get-assigned-app-links) it only returns applications that do not have "Do not display application icon to users" checked. We have a few hidden apps because they only support SP-initiated SAML, so clicking on their icon would do nothing for the users, but we still want Okta to handle the authentication.

Is there a way to get all the assigned applications of a user, regardless of the application's visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the {{url}}/api/v1/apps?filter=user.id+eq+"{{userId}}"&expand=user/{{userId}} API endpoint, instead of the appLinks endpoint.

With that call, you will get the list of all apps a user is assigned to, regardless of whether they are visible on their Okta dashboards or not.

Let me know if that helps... or not ;-)

Comment: It helps a bit, but for some reason only returns 20 apps. I had actually used that endpoint first, but couldn't remember why I commented that out until now (this project has been on and off for a while).

Comment: Hey Dave, you can actually go beyond the 20 default limit by adding the limit parameter to the query.

For instance, you would use {{url}}/api/v1/apps?filter=user.id+eq+"{{userId}}"&expand=user/{{userId}}&limit=30 if you know each user doesn't have more than 30 apps assigned to her.

Another option is to look at the Link attribute of the response header which would contain a rel="next" value with a link to the next page (the next 20 results).

Example of a Link value (apps API) could be: <{{url}}/api/v1/apps?limit=20>; rel="self", <{{url}}/api/v1/apps?after={{somevalue}}&limit=20>; rel="next"

Comment: This is very easy to test and check in Postman, for instance.

Comment: that api is not correct because it returns assigned apps of user, not app links. You can test it by creating new AWS SSO app.

Comment: @HaoVo The both return valid links, just different links. You use them exactly the same way though: issue an HTTP 302 redirect to the browser with the link. If the browser already has the Okta session cookie that's it. If you just did authentication locally pass the link to /login/sessionCookieRedirect with the session token to pick up the session cookie.